# Find a polynomial with certain conditions.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elementary-functions

Suppose that:
$$f(x) = 3\frac{x^4+x^3+x^2+1}{x^2+x-2}.$$
Find a polynomial $h(x)$ such that $f(x) + h(x)$ has horizontal asymptote of 0 as $x$ approaches positive infinity.

Comment: For an arbitrary $g(x)$ or is this missing from the post?

Comment: Any $g$ that works.... I can't find any :P

Comment: Should that say "Find a polynomial $g(x)$ ...."?

Comment: Ohhhhhhh I get it sorry let me edit.

Comment: @user161709: Have you tried factoring $f$ as a step to finding a desired $h$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Using polynomial division, we get $f(x) = 3x^2+9+\dfrac{-9x+21}{x^2+x-2}$

The $\dfrac{-9x+21}{x^2+x-2}$ term tends to $0$ as $x$ approaches $\infty$.

Comment: Does something like:
$h(x) = -(3x^2+9+\dfrac{21-9x}{x^2+x-2}) + \dfrac{1}{x}$ work?

Comment: Is that a polynomial? If not, then no.

Comment: Well... that's my question... is that a polynomial?

Comment: No it isn't. But you don't need $f(x)+h(x) = \dfrac{1}{x}$. All you need is $f(x)+h(x) \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$.

Comment: What about $h(x) = -3x^2-9$ that's certainly a polynomial!

Comment: Yes it is, and that will work.

Comment: WOAH thanks so much!

Comment: @user161709:  More simply, you can use $-3x^2$.